# Is it possible to put code inside an HTML file that is properly indented?

Tags: html

In the midst of my properly indented HTML file I have a div that looks like this:

```
            <div id="input">public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}</div>
```

This kind of bothers me because whenever I indent my HTML, I have to unindent the four lines on the bottom of this snippet so the code doesn't have extra indentation. My IDE also automatically formats the whole document when I copy and paste, so the above becomes

```
        <div id="input">
            public class Program {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello, world!");
            }
            }
        </div>
```

Is there any way to circumvent this problem, i.e. is there a mechanism similar to C# resource strings?

Comment: This is a problem of your text editor, not a programming question. What editor do you use?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but is there a reason this is a div and not a pre>code?

Comment: No, there isn't, HTML is just a markup language, not a full fledged programming language. But this looks like a good use case for a server-side programming language that builds HTML from code snippets stored elsewhere (files or database). Meanwhile, configure your editor to not do that (or find out if it has an alternative *paste* command that doesn't re-indent code).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<pre></pre>` (preformated):

```
<pre>
        public class Program {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
        }
        }
</pre>
```